# How to prove a set of inequalties in not satisfiable?

Tags: inequality, polyhedra

For the set of inequalities

$$\begin{cases}
10 a - b - c \ge d\\
 5 b - a - c \ge d\\
 2 c - a - b \ge d\\
 d \ge a + b + c\end{cases}$$

how can I show these cannot all be satisfied for $a, b, c, d$ all positive integers?

Comment: Did you try adding them ?

Comment: @wesssg - yes, and I realize now I screwed the pooch on one step, and instead of starting from scratch, kept using that incorrect result, leading to a " $^%&! - this is simple, what's the deal?" moment... DOH.

Comment: That happens to me all the time. To be honest, I didn't even know that adding them would work, I just suggested it.

Comment: Adding them does indeed work, if good weights are used! For instance, $6$ times the first plus $11$ times the second plus $22$ times the third gives $27(a+b+c)\ge 39d$ which is absurd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a+b+c=t$. Then $11a-t\ge d\ge t$, so that $a\ge \frac{2t}{11}$. Similarly, $b\ge \frac{2t}{6}$ and $c\ge \frac{2t}{3}$. Summing these up, we get:
 $$t=a+b+c\ge\frac{2t}{11}+\frac{2t}{6}+\frac{2t}{3}>t$$
which is impossible.

Comment: Thanks - I had screwed up an intermediate step, kept repeating with that incorrect step...